# How to show Google Places reviews on company website?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

There used to be a very simple way that you could embed the reviews for your company and display them on your company's website. Now Google has completely removed this feature and I have no idea now how to get this to work without manually copying/pasting the text and hard-coding it on the page. Everything I find regarding this is an outdated source.

So, how does one go about getting their own reviews on their own site from Google?

Comment: I am actually looking for the same thing! Every tutorial I come across suggests multiple reviews, but when I dig in, it's a one-by-one solution, which is obviously not ideal. Nobody wants to manually embed every review 1 at a time. +1 for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the owner of the place in Google My Business, you can retrieve all reviews for your place via Google My Business API.

Please have a look at the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data

Hope it helps!